# How to remove .html extension from a site localhosted using python 3 http.server

Tags: html, localhost, http.server

Okay so first off let me be clear that I have "BASIC" knowledge of (HTML, CSS and JS) and a little bit of Python and am not much aware of various technologies and programming stuffs. So I hope the answer would be easy.

I created a sample folder which has only two HTML files:index.html and sample.html which have almost nothing in them except a hyperlink to each other. In cmd, I used the command: `python -m http.server` to create a localhost server for the folder. But as expected it gives 404 when I type:`localhost:8000/sample` on browser and works only with `localhost:8000/sample.html`. How do I remove the .html from URL?

Comment: You can pass a custom handler that maps the extensions you want to `HTTPServer`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Elaborate what?

Comment: The solution that you told. About passing a custom handler that maps the extensions to HTTPServer

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve this but not in a general way. My code:

```
from http import SimpleHTTPServer, HTTPServer

class MyHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    url = "/path-no-html/"
    def do_GET(self):
        if url in self.path:
            self.path += ".html"
    
    SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)

with HTTPServer(('', 8000), MyHandler) as server:
    server.serve_forever()
```

Example of this being [used](https://github.com/vantage-sh/ec2instances.info/blob/master/tasks.py#L84) in ec2instances.info